# Crosstab finding values that exist in every column

Tags: excel, crosstab

I have a crosstab in excel where I have about 200,000 loans in the rows and in the columns I have price values for dates starting January 2010 and goes on until July 2018. I'm looking to find the loans that have pricing data for all of the dates that are listed in columns A to BC. If i filter every column for nonblank values i would need to do that for every date column which would be a lot. Is there an easier way to do that?

Thanks,
Ian

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just create and run a macro like this one:

```
Sub HideMyBlanks()
 For i = 1 To 26   'these are the column numbers, from A to Z here
     ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Z$200000").AutoFilter Field:=i, Criteria1:="<>"
 Next
End Sub
```

Modify those ranges-- the column numbers and the filter range-- to suit your needs.